# C# Setting diffrent value to combo box item then displayed name

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

I'm not sure if this is possible but I want my combo box to display name, but I want to use ID that is in datebase. So I have this application where you enter team of the player which is in combo box and then team get's inserted as ID into player table. Also I would like to know if this is the right way to do mysql in C# or if there is better and safer way.

```
    public void team_combo()
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connection);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ekipe", con);
        MySqlDataReader msdr;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            msdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (msdr.Read())
            {
                string team= msdr.GetString("id_ekipe");
                comboBox1.Items.Add(team);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You could create a `Team` object which will contains the ID and the name of the team and then override `toString` so it returns the name. You could also with the same object use a BindingSource and set the DisplayProperty to be the name. Or if you do not want to create an object, ComboBox have a `Format` Event that you can use to change the text before displaying it

Comment: Would you please let us know if this is Windows Forms, WPF, or something else, as there is not enough contextual information in your code to determine that.

Comment: it's windows form

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)